# Is it worth moving to the host country (i.e. America) to do an aggressive job search there?

Tags: software-industry, united-states, relocation

So as a half-decent Canadian programmer currently living/working abroad on the other side of the world, I'm pursuing the American Tech Dream, with online job applications to companies in Silicon Valley. Although I'm getting very good responses, I've noticed that my location seems to be a barrier in progressing to final-stage interviews. I'm wondering if it's worth the investment and risk to move to San Francisco and do an aggressive full time job search from there, instead of through Skype. It's expensive to live there, and I'm risking my current job and a few months of income while I'm on the search, but it may be what's necessary...

Moving there temporarily is not hard due to my Canadian citizenship (I think), and a TN visa for work should not be too difficult either.

Comment: Look at this http://www.tnvisaexpert.com/faq/question/tn-visa-qualify-software-engineer/, and also this http://www.canadiansinusa.com/Working-in-the-US/tn-visa.html - you can get into the US on a TN visa as a programmer.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, you want to be in San Francisco to do a job hunt.**

**No, you don't need any visa to *do* the job hunt.** You can actually just pop across on the standard US visa waiver program (or whatever you Canadians get when you hop over) and job hunt. You can even attend interviews - legally - on the standard visa waiver program. [This is the v. related question to that issue](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22560)

As to if you will get a job if you pop across? I don't know, no guarantee. Why not just take a holiday - an extended holiday, even - from your work and go job hunt? That is a million times safer.

I will say that applying in the US is a lot easier. Americans are actually perplexed by foreigners and foreign things (including visas). Visa questions will confound them no end - some will see it as insurmountable. They're just not used to it. They... they *think* they are, *but I can promise you they are not.*

Also note that an *easier* task would be to get a job at one of the banks in San Francisco - Wells Fargo has a sizable presence there, and so does Blackrock. Also any of the larger IT firms (you know their names). I mention this because you mention Silicon Valley (startups), and if anybody is going to balk at a visa process/onboarding a foreigner is a startup. Much easier to get a job in a bank and then look at the startups.

I was actually hired to SF from London, by a specialist firm that, well, did just that. Hired foreigners to the US. The firm is no longer around, but there are some like it - having a bing/google look might be helpful. A word of caution, I also worked via the firm [pgc group](http://thepgcgroup.com/). They're Not Recommended At All - I very nearly took them to court - so I would suggest avoiding them entirely.